# how do I move up and down an selected/ multi-selected array element/s on click up and down arrow buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, angular5, multi-select

how do I move up and down an selected/ multi-selected array element/s on click up and down arrow buttons?

javascript or vuejs answers is preferred no-Jquery, please.

Example:

```
var items = [
  {'type': 'fruit1', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit2', 'name': 'banana'},
  {'type': 'fruit3', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit4', 'name': 'cantaloupe'},
  {'type': 'fruit5', 'name': 'orange'},
  {'type': 'fruit6', 'name': 'grape'}
];
```

if I select   {'type': 'fruit3', 'name': 'apple'} and click on up arrow button

it should move one position up

```
  {'type': 'fruit1', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit3', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit2', 'name': 'banana'},
  {'type': 'fruit4', 'name': 'cantaloupe'},
  {'type': 'fruit5', 'name': 'orange'},
  {'type': 'fruit6', 'name': 'grape'}
```

same as one position down arrow button it should move one position down.

If I select multiple it should move one position up as well like below

selected from original items

```
  {'type': 'fruit3', 'name': 'apple'},
  {'type': 'fruit4', 'name': 'cantaloupe'}
```

the resulted array should be:

```
      {'type': 'fruit1', 'name': 'apple'},
      {'type': 'fruit3', 'name': 'apple'},
      {'type': 'fruit4', 'name': 'cantaloupe'},
      {'type': 'fruit2', 'name': 'banana'},
      {'type': 'fruit5', 'name': 'orange'},
      {'type': 'fruit6', 'name': 'grape'}
```

same as multi-select and click on down arrow

Here is fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/skesani/60au5yvs/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue.js you can use any of these excellent libraries

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select

https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect

They both do what you want and much more

Comment: Please check this fiddle this is what I am looking for
https://jsfiddle.net/skesani/60au5yvs/